# R for loop vs lapply (performance)

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, lapply

Which one is faster and why? If there is any - maybe it depends of the data and functions we are using. If so, how?
I've checked on some examples:

```
lista <- list(a=1:100, b=-20:500,c=300:1000,rep(1000,1000))
for(i in 1:10){ lista <- c(lista,lista)} # length==4096
```

To compare I wrote this function

```
loopfor <- function(x, fun){
    ret <- vector("list",length(x))
    for (i in seq_along(x)) { 
        ret[[i]] <- fun(x[[i]]) 
    }
    return(ret)
}

lapplyfun <- function(x, fun){
    ret <- lapply(x, fun)
    return(ret)
}
```

loopfor vs lapplyfun call
For `sum` function lapply is the winner

```
    require(microbenchmark)    
    microbenchmark(loopfor(lista,sum), lapplyfun(lista,sum),times=100)
Unit: milliseconds
                  expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
   loopfor(lista, sum) 20.496391 21.058436 21.423077 22.309260 50.80541   100
 lapplyfun(lista, sum)  8.745445  9.007782  9.342844  9.777506 15.15932   100
```

but for more complex function like `summary` the difference is really small

```
    microbenchmark(loopfor(lista,summary), lapplyfun(lista,summary),times=10)
Unit: seconds
                      expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
   loopfor(lista, summary) 2.147071 2.164275 2.186433 2.228169 2.342094    10
 lapplyfun(lista, summary) 2.024157 2.099712 2.198469 2.314902 2.550751    10
```

Any explanation, ideas? Maybe `loopfor` should be written differently to increase performance? :)

Comment: I'm confused. Your function takes an argument x, and then appears to operate directly on lista. And then you're comparing summary to sum?

Comment: About the first one you are right. About second - not :) In example with summary I changed the implementation of `loopfor`  :)

Comment: You should include the modified version of the function then. Your for loop version is spending time creating the results list. If you wrap the lapply version in a function and actually assign the result, which forces R to create the new object, I get a much smaller difference between the two.

Comment: The first one's in `ms` and the second is in seconds. The median difference in both cases are: `12.35 ms` and `9.34 ms` respectively.